# Import a project into another imported project

Tags: eclipse, apache-storm

I found this statement in the help of a project that I want to import it named "storm-
election"

This is a simple demo app based on the storm-starter project. https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter.

So, I imported storm-starter project successfully. How can I import storm-election project?

Can I import a project on another imported project ?

[image: errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a project under any project, like you create folder(s) under folder, folder(s) under project, file(s) under project and file(s) under folder.

All projects in a workspace are siblings no child and parent relationship exists between projects.

I am not able to see **storm-election** project in the link provided, but you can import this project in the same way as you imported **storm-starter** project.

Comment: Thanks, here the link of Storm-election. https://github.com/naffis/storm-election-example/blob/master/README.md . i tried to import the project as storm-starter and posted errors i faced it

Comment: The project hosted here is not proper(Project is of NO type **.project** file not exists). Import the project using `File > Import > Git > Project from GIT` use the https://github.com/naffis/storm-election-example.git as URI. No user name password the proceed next. It say no project exist. Then choose `Import as general project`. As wee see the **pom.xml** we can guess it as Maven project. After importing the project convert this to Maven project and build. I tried this but there are some unsatisfied dependencies errors exist. Ask the project hoster to update/correct the contents.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and Thanks for helping me . i tried to import project as general project but i noticed that the project haven't a build path ! and cannot run it or debug it

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 4.5 (starting from Mars M5) will include a mechanism that allows to nested projects under their parent one.
You can already give it a try by accessing the latest snapshot build of Eclipse Platform (which is a subset of the IDE, but which contains the change) http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/N20150124-1500/ , when Mars M5 is ready, you'll be able to access from http://eclipse.org/downloads a full featured IDE which also contains this feature.

Reference https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=427768