# Imported project folder icons in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My newly imported Maven project in Eclipse workpace has `J` and `M` icons on top of the project folder (Project and Package explorer) while the other imported Maven projects has only a `J` icon.

Can someone explain the difference ?

Comment: but your projects use maven feature?

Answer (score 2):

The project having **J** decorator are called Java projects and projects having **M** decorator are called Maven projects. An eclipse project can be of more than one type.

Project type can be seen in the **.project** file present inside any given project.

Typical content of **.project** file look like as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Test</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.pde.ManifestBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.pde.SchemaBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Look at  **natures** tag. All Java projects will have **org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature** nature and a single project can have multiple nature.

You can convert Java projects to Maven projects by right clicking on any Java project and selecting `Configure > Covert to Maven project`

Check the changes in **.project** file after converting.

Comment: How to convert a Maven only project to maven+ java project so that Eclipse also shows a J along with M?