# Create a new project under an existing projet

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a question about the creation of a new project under an existing Project. Assume i have these four projects in eclipse:

```
org.projet.design
org.projet.feature
org.projet.conf
org.projet.tag
```

all the project are in `projet` repository.
Now, I need to create a new Java project called `org.projet.myProject`. The problem in eclipse is, when i create new project called `myProject` and i choose `org.projet` as my default location, all the projects that are under `org.projet` will be added under `org.projet.myProject`. 
So, please how create a new Java project under an existing Project ?

Comment: Eclipse projects can't be nested.

Comment: @greg eclipse mars support nested projects. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459126/nested-projects-and-project-folders-in-eclipse

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK That is just in the Project Explorer view. The resources API still does not support projects within other projects (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=245412)