# eclipse: convert project to folder

Tags: eclipse

I have a question about folder structure in eclipse (kepler, if it could be important).
I have checked out a project that contains three child folders with text documents. I could check it out only as a project, hadn't any other options.

1. Is there any way to convert the parent project to folder since it doesn't contain any code itself?
2. Can I make a project from one of the child folders?
3. Is there any opportunity to create a project within another project if 1. is impossible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: So your child folders only store text files or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers by points.

1. Conversion not possible. You can create general project and copy the project content to this.
2. No. You can import/copy files/folders into any project.
3. No. Yes it is impossible. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457493/1391924

   ***** -> Zero or more

[image]

Comment: Thank you.May be you know whether there is an opportunity to cjeck out a folder to workspace just like a folder and not as a project?

Comment: @user2957954: The model Chandrayya G K added says that below a workspace there is just projects. Below Projects there are just folders or files. Below folders there are just files. Anything else is not allowed by that model.